# Flask app runs in Flask but not from Python

Tags: apache, flask, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a web page to execute a Python script on my Raspberry Pi.

I've installed Flask as described here, [Serving Raspberry Pi with Flask](http://mattrichardson.com/Raspberry-Pi-Flask/), and entered the sample program:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

but when I run it (`sudo python hello-flask.py`) I get and error about it know having a application or something.

I tried the same from [The flask website](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

and that runs ok, but using a different run method

```
$ FLASK_APP=hello.py flask run
```

which doesn't work for the first app.

what am I doing wrong ?

NOTE : I tried to get Apache to execute my Python scripts, but couldn't get that working either. I got it working to where I could use Python to generate HTML, but not execute a Python script to do anything with the GPIO.

Comment: please post traceback

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, but I don't know what that is. some sort of debug log or something? how do I do/find that?

Comment: when you run `python hello-flask.py` and it throws an error that is called the traceback. example -> https://gist.github.com/slinkp/7796628

Comment: This would help me understand what you mean by "I get and error about it know having a application or something." which I assume you are getting from reading the error traceback

Comment: I've given up trying to do it that way, and have tired to use php instead. That has mostly worked, apart from the part where I try and run the code the does stuff with Pimoroni lights.